# activate method of worksheet class failed - vlookup - vba

Tags: vba, vlookup

I want to use VLOOKUP command and use a range which is in sheet B (not in the activated one A). Calling the new worksheet gives me an error of  " 'runtime error 1004' activate method of worksheet class failed"

```
Public Sub Creation()

    Worksheets("A").Activate

    Randomize
    Dim code As String
    Dim hamid As Variant
    Dim Lookup_Range As Range
    Code = 100032
    Set Lookup_Range = Worksheets("B").Range("O1:P8")
    On Error Resume Next
    hamid = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(code, Lookup_Range, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0

End sub
```

I have tried using With command to call the new worksheet but I was not successful. I am new to VBA so please bear with me.

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Comment: this line
Worksheets("A").Activate

Comment: It does exist. Just when I add the lookup coed this error pops up. Otherwise the rest of the code without lookup works perfectly.

Comment: Why is it necessary to activate the sheet in the first place?

Comment: Is the worksheet protected or otherwise not accessible?

Comment: I am using the information in sheet A to run the entire code and then at some point I need to look at sheet B to use some other information.

Comment: No it is not protected.

Comment: Is this VBA a direct copy/paste from your VB editor, or did you make some edits here?   You have both `Code` and `code` which seems to point to edits, since the VBE would make them both lower-case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lookup range seems to be in worksheet B. Try activating worksheet B before using the lookup function. I've encountered issues trying to define ranges on one worksheet while having another activated:

```
Public Sub Creation()

Worksheets("A").Activate

Randomize
Dim code As String
Dim hamid As Variant
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
code = 100032
'Try here:
Worksheets("B").Activate
Set Lookup_Range = Worksheets("B").Range("O1:P8")
On Error Resume Next
'or here:
Worksheets("B").Activate
hamid = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(code, Lookup_Range, 2, False)
On Error GoTo 0
'also made 'Code' in lookup function 'code'.
End Sub
```

Comment: kpg you are right. Also after running the code I have to active the worksheet "A" again to let the code run the rest of the code.